# text zone none recognized selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm working on a bot, which makes operation automatically, but for enter the result I need to access to this text zone:

```
<input type="text"
    class="input3p ng-pristine ng-valid needsclick input3p-focused ng-touched"
    ng-click="onInputClicked()"
    ng-model="restrictedInput"
    ng-focus="onInputFocused()"
    ng-keydown="setInputValue($event, 'restrictedInput') "
    ng-keyup="setInputValue($event, 'restrictedInput') "
    answer="0"
    position="381,225"
    annunciator="none"
    size="70,50"
    chars="2"
    index="1"
    font-size="34"
    component="input3p"
    maxlength="2"
    autofocus=""
    value=""
    style="width: 70px; height: 50px; position: absolute; left: 381px; top: 225px; font-size: 34px;">
```

I've tried to pass by the class but impossible, it gives me an error message or it finds nothing. I've also tried by name, xpath, etc.

Comment: Please read [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

this css :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[ng-model='restrictedInput'][ng-click='onInputClicked()']").send_keys('some text here')
```

**update 1 :**

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("activity-view-frame"))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[ng-model='restrictedInput'][ng-click='onInputClicked()']").send_keys('some text here')
```

Comment: It's return:

```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[ng-model='restrictedInput'][ng-click='onInputClicked()']"}```

Comment: hmm, that's what I thought, I think it is in iframe, can you check in HTML dom if it's in iframe ?

Comment: Yes it's in an iframe !
```<iframe id="activity-view-frame" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 99; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; border: none;"></iframe>```
But now I don't know how can I get in the iframe for after get the input ^^'

Comment: @misterA :  Check out the updated 1 code above.